# hwriter: changing header row color of a data.table or a data.frame without row names

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to generate HTML tables using hwriter package. I would like to change the background color of the header row and of other rows, but I do not manage to do this when using a data.frame without row.names:

```
library(hwriter)

# Correctly changes the header row color
cat(hwrite(iris[1:3,],row.bgcolor=list('#aaffaa')))

## <table border="1">
## <tr>
## <td></td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Sepal.Length</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Sepal.Width</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Petal.Length</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Petal.Width</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Species</td></tr>
## <tr>
## <td>1</td><td>5.1</td><td>3.5</td><td>1.4</td><td>0.2</td><td>setosa</td></tr>
## <tr>
## <td>2</td><td>4.9</td><td>3.0</td><td>1.4</td><td>0.2</td><td>setosa</td></tr>
## <tr>
## <td>3</td><td>4.7</td><td>3.2</td><td>1.3</td><td>0.2</td><td>setosa</td></tr>
## </table>

# Now changes row 1 and row 2, instead of header row and row 1
cat(hwrite(iris[1:3,],row.bgcolor=list('#aaffaa','#aaffaa')))

## <table border="1">
## <tr>
## <td></td><td>Sepal.Length</td><td>Sepal.Width</td><td>Petal.Length</td><td>Petal.Width</td><td>Species</td></tr>
## <tr>
## <td>1</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">5.1</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">3.5</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">1.4</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">0.2</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">setosa</td></tr>
## <tr>
## <td>2</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">4.9</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">3.0</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">1.4</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">0.2</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">setosa</td></tr>
## <tr>
## <td>3</td><td>4.7</td><td>3.2</td><td>1.3</td><td>0.2</td><td>setosa</td></tr>
## </table>
```

Is there any workaround or I am forced to used row names? My problem is that I extensively use data.tables and they do not have row names...

Comment: There is an option `keep.rownames` in `data.table`, but it will generate a column

Comment: @akrun Unfortunately it did not work...

Answer (score 2):

You could always just write your own `hwrite` method for `data.table`. For example the following should work:

```
# required packages
pkgs2load <- c('hwriter', 'data.table')
sapply(pkgs2load, require, character.only=TRUE)
# data.table hwrite method
hwrite.data.table <- function(x, ...){
  # change x to matrix
  mat <- as.matrix(x)
  rownames(mat) <- 1L:nrow(mat)
  # change row.bgcolor appropriately
  lst <- list(...)
  if (length(lst$row.bgcolor) > 1 & is.null(names(lst$row.bgcolor))) 
    names(lst$row.bgcolor) <- c('', 1L:(length(lst$row.bgcolor)-1L))
  # call hwrite
  do.call(hwrite, c(list(mat), lst))
}
dt <- data.table(iris[1:3,])
cat(hwrite(dt,row.bgcolor=list('#aaffaa', '#aaffaa')))

## <table border="1">
## <tr>
## <td></td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Sepal.Length</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Sepal.Width</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Petal.Length</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Petal.Width</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">Species</td></tr>
## <tr>
## <td>1</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">5.1</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">3.5</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">1.4</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">0.2</td><td bgcolor="#aaffaa">setosa</td>    ## </tr>
## <tr>
## <td>2</td><td>4.9</td><td>3.0</td><td>1.4</td><td>0.2</td><td>setosa</td></tr>
## <tr>
## <td>3</td><td>4.7</td><td>3.2</td><td>1.3</td><td>0.2</td><td>setosa</td></tr>
## </table>
```

Comment: Thanks @shadow, but it looks a complicated solution for something that should be simple... If I need to do things this way then I would simply use as.data.frame and proceed with it.